# How to get Lat and Lng from StandaloneSearchBox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps

I use the `react-google-maps` `StandaloneSearchBox` and query the locations of my points of interest. This works as far as it goes. However, I get back functions for the location and not the actual value. How do I actually get the lat and lng values similar to the viewport.

```
geometry:
 location: _.bf
   lat: ƒ ()
   lng: ƒ ()

 viewport: _.Wf
   Bb: Vf {g: 41.4022605197085, h: 41.4049584802915}
   Ra: Qf {g: 2.173047169708498, h: 2.175745130291502}
```

Comment: `geometry.location.lat()` and `geometry.location.lng()`

Comment: Works. If you want to post it at answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the `lat` and `lng` functions to get the values.

- `geometry.location.lat()` -> latitude value
- `geometry.location.lng()` -> longitude value